# How to get the previous run time in APScheduler?

Tags: cron, apscheduler

I know there's `job.next_run_time` to get the next run, but anyway to calculate what would have been the previous run time?

Comment: Maybe the job itself can write somewhere when it was run?

Comment: That would work if I was using it as intended, but I'm only using the parser part of it to parse out quartz cron schedule from another system.

Comment: You lost me. Can you please add some code to the question, so we get more context what you are trying to do.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa A bit late to the party but I think he means he's using APScheduler for cron syntax parsing only, and not for its actual scheduler. I'm looking at a similar need now and will be looking at https://github.com/josiahcarlson/parse-crontab if APScheduler doesn't give me something already

Answer (score 1):

The triggers don't work backwards, so you would have to add that functionality to them yourself.